# How text(adj=...) works?

Tags: r

```
plot(-10:10, -10:10)
R> text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', pos=2, srt=90, adj=c(0,0))
R> text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', pos=2, srt=90, adj=c(1,0))
R> text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', pos=2, srt=90, adj=c(10,0))
R> text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', pos=2, srt=90, adj=c(10,1))
R> text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', pos=2, srt=90, adj=c(10,10))
```

I tried the above command with different `adj`. But I don't see anything changed. I many misunderstand the meaning of adj.

Could you show me how to adjust `adj` so that the results are different?

Answer (score 1):

From the `?text` help page

> **pos**  a position specifier for the text. If specified this overrides any `adj` value given. Values of 1, 2, 3 and 4, respectively indicate positions below, to the left of, above and to the right of the specified (x,y) coordinates.

So when you use `pos=`, the value for `adj=` is ignored. If you want to use `adj=`, you can't also use `pos=`. Also the values passed to `adj=` should be on the 0-1 scale. Values above 1 seem to just be treated as 1.

```
plot(-10:10, -10:10)
text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', adj=c(0,0), col="red")
text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', adj=c(1,0), col="blue")
text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', adj=c(.5,0), col="green")
text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', adj=c(.5,1) , col="orange")
text(x=0, y=0, 'xxxx', adj=c(.5,.5), col="purple")
```

[image]